# Sleep function in iOS with Spinner

Tags: ios, spinner, sleep, nsthread

I have a spinner function to start and stop from beginning of process to end. But since process takes milliseconds, i can't really keep spinner turning.

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0]; //method 1
sleep(2); //method2
```

Then i used Sleep methods to standby the code and let spinner turn, but it stops the Thread, then spinner will stop as well. This is the code:

```
if (indexPath.row == 1)
{
    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES]; //spinner starts

    EmployeeDataSource *aaa=[[EmployeeDataSource alloc]init];
    [aaa Logout: ^(BOOL results){
        if(results == YES){

        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0]; //sleeping thread

        //if logout succesfull go to login page
        LoginViewController *lv = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginsb"];

            [self presentViewController:lv animated:NO completion:nil];

            [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES]; //spinner ends

        }
        else{

            NSLog(@"logout not succesfull");
        }           
}];
```

I want `[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];` to work for 2 seconds at least, but it ends in less than a second since normal process is fast? How can i extend this time, sleep method seems not suitable. Do you have any idea? Thank you.

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve? Sleeping a thread is almost NEVER the answer. Especially the main thread. It will just look like your app has crashed.

Comment: i want [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES]; to work for 2 seconds at least. but it ends in less than a second since process is fast? How can i extend this time, sleep method seems not suitable.

Comment: Search for dispatch after delay on Google. There are many answer and these will all work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should do your stuff after some delay.
for that please use this

```
[self performSelector:@selector(method) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```

here Delay is in second, so you can set it accordingly.

Or you can go with this as well.

```
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        //Do you stuff here...
    });
```

May this help you.

Comment: thanks. [self performSelector:@selector(method) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0]; helped!